# How to get most retrieved items from an elasticsearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, kibana

I have uploaded some data to elasticsearch and I would like to keep track of how many times a data point is returned by past searches, that is to say, the most popular searched items.

Does elasticsearch provide such functionality to achieve this without implementing and updating a counter myself?

Cheers.

Comment: you will have to implement this yourself